# Color-code cells in HTML mail based on criteria

Tags: html, email, powershell

I have a simple script which checks disk space on remote servers, it's got a simple output format which is as follows

[image]

What I'd like to do, is color code the individual cells based on their values. Specifically, I'd like to have the cell shaded RED if the free space is less than 300 on any of the drives. What's the easiest means to do this based on the results being sent by PowerShell `Send-MailMessage` in HTML format?

Here's the code i've got that collects the data from the remote servers:

```
function Set-AlternatingRows {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string]$Line,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$CSSEvenClass,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$CSSOddClass
    )
    Begin {
        $ClassName = $CSSEvenClass
    }
    Process {
        if ($Line.Contains("<tr><td>")) {
            $Line = $Line.Replace("<tr>","<tr class=""$ClassName"">")
            if ($ClassName -eq $CSSEvenClass) {
                $ClassName = $CSSOddClass
            } else {
                $ClassName = $CSSEvenClass
            }
        }
        return $Line
    }
}

foreach ($Item in $InputCSV) {
    Write-Host "Checking $($Item.Server) now"
    $ShortDate = (Get-Date).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')

    $Ping = PingEM $Item.Server

    ### Check if server is online before proceeding
    if ($Ping -eq "Online") {
        Write-Host "$($Item.Server) is Online" -ForegroundColor Green

        $FreeSpaceAll = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -filter "DriveType=3" -Computer $($Item.Server) |
                        Select SystemName, DeviceID, VolumeName,
                            @{Name="Total Size (GB)";E={"{0:N1}" -f($_.Size/1gb)}},
                            @{Name="Free Space (GB)";E={"{0:N1}" -f($_.Freespace/1gb)}}
        $FreeSpaceC = $FreeSpaceAll | Where {$_.DeviceID -eq "C:"}  | Select -expand "Free Space (GB)"
        $FreeSpaceD = $FreeSpaceAll | Where {$_.DeviceID -eq "D:"}  | Select -expand "Free Space (GB)"
        $FreeSpaceE = $FreeSpaceAll | Where {$_.DeviceID -eq "E:"}  | Select -expand "Free Space (GB)"
    } # Ping

    $outarray += New-Object PsObject -Property @{
        Server = $Item.Server
        FreeSpaceAll = $FreeSpaceAll
        FreeSpaceC = $FreeSpaceC
        FreeSpaceD = $FreeSpaceD
        FreeSpaceE = $FreeSpaceE
        PingResults = $Ping
    } # OutArray New-Object
} # For

$Head = Get-Content "$Dir\CSS.txt"
$Pre = "This email contains info on C/D/E free space on remote servers<br>    <br>" 
$Pre += "The below report data is available in Excel .CSV format $Link1.     After 7 days, the reports will be moved $Link2 <br><br>"

$Output = $OutArray |
          Select Server, PingResults, @{E={$_.FreeSpaceC};Label="Free Space C: (GB)"},
              @{E={$_.FreeSpaceD};Label="Free Space D: (GB)"},
              @{E={$_.FreeSpaceE};Label="Free Space E: (GB)"} |
    ConvertTo-Html -Head $Head -PreContent $Pre -As Table | Set-AlternatingRows -CSSOddClass odd -CSSEvenClass even |
    Out-String

$Subject = "($ScriptVer) - file server C/D/E free space report"
$TSBody = ""
$TSBody += "<font face ='arial' color='black'>$Output </font><br><br>"

Send-NailMessage $To -Subject $Subject -Body $TSbody -BodyAsHtml -From $From -SmtpServer $Mailer
```

Comment: You are going to have to create the HTML table yourself since the builtins dont support conditional formatting like you are asking for. Is there something you have tried? i show no attempt at even making any HTML output here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662940/convertto-html-highlight-the-cells-with-special-values?

Comment: Post updated with missing code. I looked at the following StackoverFlow  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559233/technique-for-selectively-formatting-data-in-a-powershell-pipeline-and-output-as) post, but was unable to make it work with my code, as the example uses .XML, not HTML, and i'm not familiar with how to convert XML to HTML for use with the Powershell send-message function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559233/technique-for-selectively-formatting-data-in-a-powershell-pipeline-and-output-as Looks perfect! I'll try that out tomorrow. Thank you, Matt.

Comment: Both answers show similar logic but the second answer in my linked question does have HTML as its example.

Comment: Works! Thx very much Matt!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written this so that it generally does what you want. It is already set to go with HTML tables and an free relay server email provider. This script takes one text input file that you can specify at the top. This text file will contain all of the server names that you want to check, on their own line. Example below. If you want to use your own email provider, you can just replace all the smtp info. Otherwise, it DOES REQUIRE admin priviledges to be run successfully. These credentials can be entered at the top of the script where `$cred` is specified. You will also need to change the `$servers` variable to point to your list of server names to check against. It currently only selects the C drive, but you can easily edit that as well as add a column for ping results.

Example of **C:\temp\servers.txt**

```
hqdc01
hqdc02
hqdc03
hqfile01
hqfile02
hqmail01
hqservices01
hqsql01
hqsql02
```

The .ps1 script:

```
    $cred = Get-Credential -Credential 'domain\domainadminuser'
    $ServerName = Get-Content "C:\temp\servers.txt"
    $ConvertToGB = (1024 * 1024 * 1024)
    $enter1 = "`r"
    $enter2 = "`r`n"

    # Smtp deets
    $smtpServer = "relay.appriver.com"
    $smtpPort = "2525"
    $smtpFrom = "from@from.com"
    $smtpTo = "myself@myself.com"
    $messageSubject = "Daily Server Report"

    # Set up an SmtpClient
    $smtpClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient
    $smtpClient.Host = $smtpServer
    $smtpClient.Port = $smtpPort

    # Create the MailMessage 
    $mailMessage = New-Object Net.Mail.MailMessage
    $mailMessage.From = $smtpFrom
    $mailMessage.To.Add($smtpTo)
    $mailMessage.Subject = $messageSubject
    $mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = $true

    # style
    $htmlReport += "<style>"
    $htmlReport += "BODY{background-color:white;}"
    $htmlReport += "TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}"
    $htmlReport += "TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 0px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}"
    $htmlReport += "TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 0px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}"
    $htmlReport += "</style>"


    # table
$htmlReport += "<table>"
$htmlReport += "`n"
$htmlReport += "<tr>"
$htmlReport += "<th>ServerName</th>"
$htmlReport += "<th>Total C:</th>"
$htmlReport += "<th>Free C:</th>"
$htmlReport += "<th>% Free C:</th>"
$htmlReport += "<th>Total D:</th>"
$htmlReport += "<th>Free D:</th>"
$htmlReport += "<th>% Free D:</th>"
$htmlReport += "<th>Total E:</th>"
$htmlReport += "<th>Free E:</th>"
$htmlReport += "<th>% Free E:</th>"
$htmlReport += "</tr>"
foreach($Server in $ServerName)
{
    #Get info on all C: drives
    $diskC = Get-WmiObject -Credential $cred Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $Server -Filter "DeviceID='C:'" | Select-Object Size,FreeSpace
    $htmlReport += "<tr>"
    $htmlReport += "<td>$($Server)</td>"
    try
    {
        $htmlReport += "<td>$([Math]::Truncate($diskC.Size / $ConvertToGB))  GB </td>"
    }
    catch
    {
        $htmlReport += "<td>NA</td>"
    }
    try
    {
        $htmlReport += "<td>$([Math]::Truncate($diskC.FreeSpace / $ConvertToGB))  GB </td>"
    }
    catch
    {
        $htmlReport += "<td>NA</td>"
    }   
    try
    {
        if([Math]::Truncate(($diskC.FreeSpace / $diskC.size) * 100) -le 10)
        {
            $htmlReport += "<td><font color=red> $([Math]::Truncate(($diskC.FreeSpace / $diskC.size) * 100))  % </font></td>"
        }
        if([Math]::Truncate(($diskC.FreeSpace / $diskC.size) * 100) -gt 10 -and [Math]::Truncate(($diskC.FreeSpace / $diskC.size) * 100) -le 20)
        {
            $htmlReport += "<td><font color=orange> $([Math]::Truncate(($diskC.FreeSpace / $diskC.size) * 100))  % </font></td>"
        }
        if([Math]::Truncate(($diskC.FreeSpace / $diskC.size) * 100) -gt 20)
        {
            $htmlReport += "<td><font color=green> $([Math]::Truncate(($diskC.FreeSpace / $diskC.size) * 100))  % </font></td>"
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        $htmlReport += "<td>NA</td>"
    }   

    #Get info on all D: drives
    $diskD = Get-WmiObject -Credential $cred Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $Server -Filter "DeviceID='D:'" | Select-Object Size,FreeSpace
    try
    {
        $htmlReport += "<td>$([Math]::Truncate($diskD.Size / $ConvertToGB))  GB </td>"
    }
    catch
    {
        $htmlReport += "<td>NA</td>"
    }
    try
    {
        $htmlReport += "<td>$([Math]::Truncate($diskD.FreeSpace / $ConvertToGB))  GB </td>"
    }
    catch
    {
        $htmlReport += "<td>NA</td>"
    }
    try
    {
        if([Math]::Truncate(($diskE.FreeSpace / $diskE.size) * 100) -le 10)
        {
            $htmlReport += "<td><font color=red> $([Math]::Truncate(($diskD.FreeSpace / $diskD.size) * 100))  % </font></td>"
        }
        if([Math]::Truncate(($diskE.FreeSpace / $diskE.size) * 100) -gt 10 -and [Math]::Truncate(($diskD.FreeSpace / $diskD.size) * 100) -le 20)
        {
            $htmlReport += "<td><font color=orange> $([Math]::Truncate(($diskD.FreeSpace / $diskD.size) * 100))  % </font></td>"
        }
        if([Math]::Truncate(($diskE.FreeSpace / $diskE.size) * 100) -gt 20)
        {
            $htmlReport += "<td><font color=green> $([Math]::Truncate(($diskD.FreeSpace / $diskD.size) * 100))  % </font></td>"
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        $htmlReport += "<td>NA</td>"
    }

    #Get info on all E: drives
    $diskE = Get-WmiObject -Credential $cred Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $Server -Filter "DeviceID='E:'" | Select-Object Size,FreeSpace
    try
    {
        $htmlReport += "<td>$([Math]::Truncate($diskE.Size / $ConvertToGB))  GB </td>"
    }
    catch
    {
        $htmlReport += "<td>NA</td>"
    }
    try
    {
        $htmlReport += "<td>$([Math]::Truncate($diskE.FreeSpace / $ConvertToGB))  GB </td>"
    }
    catch
    {
        $htmlReport += "<td>NA</td>"
    }
    try
    {
        if([Math]::Truncate(($diskE.FreeSpace / $diskE.size) * 100) -le 10)
        {
            $htmlReport += "<td><font color=red> $([Math]::Truncate(($diskE.FreeSpace / $diskE.size) * 100))  % </font></td>"
        }
        if([Math]::Truncate(($diskE.FreeSpace / $diskE.size) * 100) -gt 10 -and [Math]::Truncate(($diskE.FreeSpace / $diskE.size) * 100) -le 20)
        {
            $htmlReport += "<td><font color=orange> $([Math]::Truncate(($diskE.FreeSpace / $diskE.size) * 100))  % </font></td>"
        }
        if([Math]::Truncate(($diskE.FreeSpace / $diskE.size) * 100) -gt 20)
        {
            $htmlReport += "<td><font color=green> $([Math]::Truncate(($diskE.FreeSpace / $diskE.size) * 100))  % </font></td>"
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        $htmlReport += "<td>NA</td>"
    }
    $htmlReport += "</tr>"
}

$htmlReport += "</table>"



# Now create an AlternateView from the HTML contents
$messageBody = [Net.Mail.AlternateView]::CreateAlternateViewFromString($htmlReport, 'text/html')

# Add the HTML view to the MailMessage
$mailMessage.AlternateViews.Add($messageBody)

# And finally send the message
$smtpClient.Send($mailMessage)
pause
```

And last but not least, here is a picture of the sample email that you will get with this embedded table:
[image: htmltable]

Comment: Thank you for this, this does appear to be a lot less code than what i've currently got, however, it's not using send-message, as i require. I should be able to use most of what you've got, i'll try that today/tomorrow and then choose one of the responses as the answer.

Comment: Ah, yes. It should be very simple to swap out system.net.mail for send-mailmessage. If I get around to it, I will edit my code to support both.

Comment: @Kenny I added try/catch blocks so it cant fail if your server does not have the particular drive letter as well added the D: and E: drives.